# Preencher campos do formulário com dados da API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, formulário

Bom dia, tenho um formulário onde o usuário digita o código de um produto.
Ao digitar o código uma API é acionada e ela retornar os dados do produto informado.

Minha duvida agora é como fazer para que os campos do formulário sejam preenchidos com os dados que a API retornou. Alguém poderia me ajudar, ficaria grato.

OBS: backend é em NodeJS e front é em AngularJS

Esse é o código que retorna a API:

```
   vm.selectAtivoPlaca = function () {
        const vm = this

        const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/produto?placa=${vm.ativo.placa}`
        console.log(url)

        $http.get(`${url}&idempresa=${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_app_user")).user.idempresa}&status=true`).then(function (response) {
            vm.ativocadastros = response.data
            console.log(vm.ativocadastros)
        })
    }
```

Aqui é o campo do formulário onde o usuário digita a código.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">
    <p><label>Placa</label></p>
    <input type="text" ng-model="atiCtrl.ativo.placa" class="form-group" ng-blur="atiCtrl.selectAtivoPlaca()" />
</div>
```

[image: Aqui é o retorno da API]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai criar os inputs dos campos que você quer, cada um com seu próprio `ng-model`.

Por exemplo: `<input type="text" ng-model="marca" class="form-group"  />`

Dentro do ***then*** você insere o valor nas variáveis ( **marca** é só um exemplo, você adapta para a sua realidade):

```
  vm.selectAtivoPlaca = function () {
      const vm = this

      const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/produto?placa=${vm.ativo.placa}`
      console.log(url)

      $http.get(`${url}&idempresa=${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("_app_user")).user.idempresa}&status=true`)
        .then(function (response) {
          vm.ativocadastros = response.data
          vm.marca = vm.ativocadastros.marca
          console.log(vm.ativocadastros)
        })
```

Dessa forma, o valor vai para o `ng-model` que você quer.

Obs.: É uma boa prática colocar ponto e virgula `;` no final de cada linha. É mais seguro ;)